# How to use one environment variable when calling a bash script repeatedly

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a task to monitor the system with a quota, if the monitored result is over the quota, send a warning email. But this monitor program should be called once in half an hour, after one warning email is sent out, the next time if the monitored state is still the same as last time, there is no need to send the same warning email again.

In order to do this, I would like to make use of environment variable to store the state of the last monitored result, so that the next time it can be checked and duplicate email would not be sent. One of my solution is to add or update the `export` syntax in `.bashrc`, but in order to activate the updated `export` syntax, I have to run `bash`, which might be unnecessary.

So I would like ask is there any way to update the environment variable so that every time when the monitor program Bash script is called, it gets the fresh updated value?

Comment: Why don't you store this info in a specific file (not in `.bashrc`) and you keep updating its value?

Comment: It is only one value, why should I store it in a specified file? and the specified file might be deleted by accident

Comment: First of all, note that running `bash` is not necessary. To load the values in `.bashrc` you just have to run `source ~/.bashrc`. This being said, I do think that variables from a program should be in a different place, not to confuse: for example `/usr/bin/myprogram/vars`.

Comment: @fedorqui Great hint from u :) I think I will make use of a file, i.e. log file

Comment: @fedorqui I like your response, but suggest against using `/usr/bin` as a starting location. Consider something under `/var`.

Comment: @Eric this is a good point. Checking [The Linux Filesystem -> Locations](http://swift.siphos.be/linux_sea/linuxfs.html) I see that `/var` could well be, but also `/usr` may. Not sure about what is the generic approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self contained solution using a heredoc.  At first glance it may seem an elaborate and inperfect solution, it does have its uses in that it's resilient and it works well when deploying across more than one machine, requires no special monitoring or permissions of external files, and most importantly, there are no unwanted surprises with environment.

This example uses **bash**, but it will work with **sh** if the `$thisfile` variable is set manually, or another way.

This example assumes that `20` is already in the script file as `mymonitorvalue`, and uses argument **$1** as a proof of concept.  You would obviously change **`newval="$1"`** to whatever calculates the quota:

---

### Example usage:

```
#bash $>./script 10
Value from previous run was 20
Value from this test was 10
Updating value ...

#bash $>./script 10
not doing anything ... result is the same as last time

#bash $>
```

---

### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

thisfile="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" ; thisfile="${DIR}${0}"

read -d '' currentvalue <<'EOF'
mymonitorval=20
EOF

eval "$currentvalue"

function changeval () { 
sed -E -i "s/(^mymonitorval\=)(.*)/mymonitorval\="$1"/g" "$thisfile"
}

newvalue="$1"

if [[ "$newvalue" != "$mymonitorval" ]]; then 
    echo "Value from previous run was $mymonitorval"
    echo "Value from this test was "$1""
    echo "Updating value ..."
    changeval "$newvalue"
else
    echo "not doing anything ... result is the same as last time" 
fi
```

---

### Explanation:

`thisfile=` can be set manually for script location.  This example uses the automated solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128

`read -d`...`EOF` is the heredoc which is saved into variable `$currentvalue`

`eval "$currentvalue"` in this case is the equivalent of typing `mymonitorval=10` into a terminal

`function changeval...}` updates the contents of the heredoc **in place** (it changes the physical .sh script file)

`newvalue="$1"` is for the purpose of testing.  `$newvalue` would be determined by whatever your script is that is calculating quota

`if....` block is to perform two alternate sets of actions depending on whether `$newvalue` is the same as it was last time or not.

Answer (score 0):

Store environment variable in different .file and then source <.file>